# Refreshing user auth server side in NextJS?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, next.js

I'm trying to refresh the users auth token on the server in NextJS, currently I have the token set in cookies that I access like this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
    const cookies = nookies.get(ctx);
    try {
        const client = useClient(cookies.token);
    // etc
    }
}
```

unfortunately if the token has expired this will fail with the token has expired error.

I do have access to the refresh token but not sure how to use it, firebase.auth().currentUser is undefined in getServersideProps as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue using NuxtJS and the easiest way is to redirect user to a different page where you can get a new Firebase ID Token on client side and then refresh the cookie. For example, you may redirect to a page something like `https://domain.tld/auth/refresh?redirect_uri=/dashboard`. The query parameter redirect_uri tells where the user was and must be redirected back after refreshing the token.

If you want to avoid the redirect, you would have to store the "Refresh Token" on your server side. I am not sure how secure that will be but don't store refresh token in cookies. But just in case you are wondering how to get new Firebase ID Token using the refresh token, you can make a POST request to this URL:

```
https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=FirebasePublicAPIKey
```

The API key is available in your Firebase Config. The body for this POST request seems to be URL encoded and has `grant_type` and `refresh_token` fields.

Here's a cURL request for the same:

```
curl "https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=firebaseAPIKey" \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -X POST \
  -F 'grant_type=refresh_token' \
  -F 'refresh_token=firebaseRefreshToken'
```

I just used Chrome DevTools to check how tokens are refresh and found that.

The first method sounds safer to me and I personally use it over storing refresh tokens somewhere on server or cookies. In fact, I use custom JWT tokens from my server in cookies instead of Firebase ID Tokens themselves.