# How to secure Firestore database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a CRUD application (No login/signup application), data stored in firestore database, It is just a Angular application which connects firestore db. My firestore security rules are `allow read, write true`, So that I can access my firestore db.

This is the format of actual firebase configuration

```
  {
    apiKey: "xxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxx-fi.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxx-fi.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xx-fi",
    storageBucket: "xx-fi.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
    appId: "1:xxx:web:36344b5bddd03c3bcef663"
}
```

I have found that firebase is enough to know `projectId` and not to send full above configuration.

```
{
  projectId: "xxxx-fi"
}
```

Just by using above `projectId` I could read and write in my firestore db. I felt this is security risk, if someone knows my projectId, for them, it is easy to read/write in my db.

So, In order to move my application to production level, How to secure my firestore db?

**Note:** I have seen already people have posted for the same kind of issue in stackoverflow. but couldn't understand it clearly. Kindly share your solutions clearly. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project ID is required so the Firebase SDK will know where to read/write data from/to. Yes, anyone with that project ID can communicate with your Firebase project and that's where [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) come in.

`allow read, write: if true` will allow anyone to read and write to your database.

```
allow read: if true;
allow write: if false;
```

These rules will allow anyone to read but no one to write to the database. Now if you want to write to database you would have to do so directly from the Firebase console.

Other option would be using Firebase Auth and creating and account for yourself only. Then you can write the following rule:

```
allow write: if request.auth.uid === "yourFirebaseUID";
```

This will allow only your account to write to database.

If you want to allow multiple usres to write to your database then you can use [Firebase Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) which are kind of like roles on Discord. You can then check for the claim like this:

```
allow write: if request.auth.token.writerClaim == true;
```

Can you specify what kind of rules you are looking for? I maybe able to help you write rules that way or suggest any workarounds.

Comment: Thank you! Here, what is the role of other attributes like apiKey, apiId. etc. I really dont understand why firebase have those attributes if they need only projectId

Comment: @RenceAbi the API key is used for other services like Firebase Auth, Storage, etc which mostly involves Google Cloud in play. Database URL is required for using RTDB and same for storage bucket URL. To test that out yourself, you can use storage and authentication and checkout network tab in browser dev tools. You will see the API key in the requests made to the APIs. If the answer was helpful you can accept  & upvote it else feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: You can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68057853/13130697) where I've posted a sample API request which uses the Firebase API key